# If $x_1,...,x_n \in \mathfrak m$ is $M$-regular sequence, which $\operatorname{Tor}^R_i(M,R/(x_1,...,x_n))$ are $0$?

Tags: commutative-algebra, homological-algebra, derived-functors

Let $(R,\mathfrak m)$ be a Noetherian local ring. Let $M$ be a finitely generated $R$-module. If $x\in \mathfrak m$ is a non-zero-divisor on $M$, then it is easy to see $\operatorname{Tor}^R_1(M,R/(x))=0$.

My question is the following:

> If $x_1,...,x_n \in \mathfrak m$ is an $M$-[regular sequence](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_sequence), then is it true that $\operatorname{Tor}^R_i(M,R/(x_1,...,x_n))=0$ for all $i=1,...,n$ ? Or at least can we say $\operatorname{Tor}^R_1(M,R/(x_1,...,x_n))=0$, or $\operatorname{Tor}^R_n(M,R/(x_1,...,x_n))=0$ ?

I already know that the answer is affirmative if the sequence is also $R$-regular, but I do NOT want to assume that.

Here's the proof of $n=1$ case that I know: Consider the beginning of a free resolution of $R/(x)$: $F_2\to R \xrightarrow{\cdot x} R \to R/(x)\to 0$, where $F_2$ is some free module. To compute $\operatorname{Tor}^R_1(M,R/(x))$ we crop $R/(x)$ out of this and tensor with $M$ to get the complex $F_2\otimes_R M \to M \xrightarrow{\cdot x} M\to 0 $ , and the homology at the first spot is $\operatorname{Tor}^R_1(M,R/(x))$. But $x$ is $M$-regular, so $\operatorname{Tor}^R_1(M,R/(x))=\ker \{M \xrightarrow{\cdot x} M\}/Im \{F_2\otimes_R M \to M\}=0/Im \{F_2\otimes_R M \to M\}=0.$

Please help me with the general version.

Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

(1) It is true in general that $\operatorname{Tor}_1^R(M,R/(x_1,\dots,x_n))=0$.
To see this, consider the beginning of the Koszul complex for $(R,x_1,\dots,x_n)$:
$$
\bigwedge^2R^{\oplus n}\to R^{\oplus n}\xrightarrow{
\begin{pmatrix}
x_1&\dots&x_n
\end{pmatrix}
}R\to R/(x_1,\dots,x_n)\to 0.
$$
This is in general not exact at $R^{\oplus n}$, but if we add some free $R$-module $F$ to the leftmost term, we get an $R$-free resolution of $R/(x_1,\dots,x_n)$:
$$
F \oplus \bigwedge^2R^{\oplus n}\to R^{\oplus n}\to R\to R/(x_1,\dots,x_n)\to 0.
$$
Cutting out $R/(x_1,\dots,x_n)$ and tensoring with $M$, we obtain a complex
$$
(M\otimes_R F)\oplus \biggl(M\otimes_R\bigwedge^2R^{\oplus n}\biggr)\to M^{\oplus n}\to M
$$
whose cohomology at the middle gives $\operatorname{Tor}_1^R(M,R/(x_1,\dots,x_n)$.
Now, since $x_1,\dots,x_n$ is an $M$-regular sequence, the Koszul complex for $(M,x_1,\dots,x_n)$ is exact.
Therefore the above complex is exact at the middle, so we get $\operatorname{Tor}_1^R(M,R/(x_1,\dots,x_n))=0$.

(2) There is an example such that $\operatorname{Tor}_2^R(M,R/(x_1,x_2))\neq 0$.
Namely, let $k$ be a field and set $R=k[X,Y,Z]_{(X,Y,Z)}/(XY,XZ)$, $M=R/(X)\simeq k[Y,Z]_{(Y,Z)}$.
Then $Y,Z$ is obviously an $M$-regular sequence, but it is not an $R$-regular sequence.
One can check that the following sequence gives an $R$-free resolution of $M$:
$$
R^{\oplus 3}
\xrightarrow{
\begin{pmatrix}
Z&X&0\\
-Y&0&X
\end{pmatrix}
}
R^{\oplus 2}
\xrightarrow{
\begin{pmatrix}
Y&Z
\end{pmatrix}
}
R\xrightarrow{X}R\to M\to 0.
$$
Cutting out $M$ and tensoring with $R/(Y,Z)$, we obtain a complex
$$
R/(Y,Z)^{\oplus 3}\xrightarrow{
\begin{pmatrix}
0&X&0\\
0&0&X
\end{pmatrix}
}
R/(Y,Z)^{\oplus 2}\xrightarrow{
\begin{pmatrix}
0&0
\end{pmatrix}
}
R/(Y,Z)\xrightarrow{X}R/(Y,Z)
$$
whose cohomology at $R/(Y,Z)^{\oplus 2}$ gives $\operatorname{Tor}_2^R(M,R/(Y,Z))$.
Therefore we get $\operatorname{Tor}_2^R(M,R/(Y,Z))\simeq k^{\oplus 2}\neq 0$.

Comment: Sorry for being very late in seeing this, but I have a couple of questions: why adding $F$ to the very left most module make the complex exact?

Comment: It's fine!  First note that we don't need a full resolution of $R/(x_1,\dots,x_n)$, but the first three terms of it.  The Koszul complex is already exact at $R$ and $R/(x_1,\dots,x_n)$, so we just have to kill the cohomology group $H$ at $R^{\oplus n}$.  Choosing $F\to H$ from a free module and adding $F$ to the leftmost term, we can kill $H$.

Comment: Under the same hypothesis, does it also hold that $\operatorname{Tor}_1^R(M,R/(x_1,\dots,x_n)^l)=0$ for all integer $l>1$? When $M$ is cyclic, this was shown in https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/268542/ideals-generated-by-regular-sequences-and-the-vanishing-of-operatornametor

Answer (score 0):

$\def\Tor{\operatorname{Tor}}$ There is no need to invoke the Koszul complex as Jun Koizumi did. In Bruns, Herzog, *Cohen-Macaulay Rings*, rev. ed., we find:

> **Exercise 1.1.12.** (a) Prove that if $\mathbf{x}=x_1,\dots,x_n$ is a weak $M$-sequence, then $\Tor^R_1(M,R/(\mathbf{x}))=0$.
>
> (b) Prove that if, in addition, $\mathbf{x}$ is a weak $R$-sequence, then $\Tor_i^R(M,R/(\mathbf{x}))=0$ for all $i\geq 0$.

Here's how one does it:

(a) From the same book, we consider:

> **Proposition 1.1.4.** Let $R$ be a ring, $M$ an $R$-module, and $\mathbf{x}=x_1,\dots,x_n$ a weak $M$-sequence. Then an exact sequence
> $$
> N_2\xrightarrow{\varphi_2}N_1\xrightarrow{\varphi_1}N_0\xrightarrow{\varphi_0}M\to 0
> $$
> of $R$-modules induces an exact sequence
> $$
> N_2/\mathbf{x}N_2\to N_1/\mathbf{x}N_1\to N_0/\mathbf{x}N_0\to M\to 0.
> $$

Thus, considering any projective resolution $P_\bullet\to M$ of $M$, we get that $0=H_1(P_\bullet\otimes_R R/(\mathbf{x}))=\Tor^R_1(M,R/(\mathbf{x}))$.

(b) We now use:

> **Proposition 1.1.5.** Let $R$ be a ring and
> $$
> N_\bullet:\cdots\to N_m\xrightarrow{\varphi_m}N_{m-1}\to\cdots\to N_0\xrightarrow{\varphi_0}N_{-1}\to 0
> $$
> an exact complex of $R$-modules. If $\mathbf{x}$ is weakly $N_i$-regular for all $i$, then $N_\bullet\otimes_R R/(\mathbf{x})$ is exact again.

The sequence $\mathbf{x}$ being $R$-regular implies $F$-regularity for any free $R$-module $F$. Thus, if $F_\bullet\to M$ is a free resolution of $M$, then for $i>0$, the proposition gives $0=H_i(F_\bullet\otimes_R R/(\mathbf{x}))=\Tor^R_i(M,R/(\mathbf{x}))$.